# suppose that the critical points of f are all non-degenerate, show that f does not have maximum or minimum

Tags: analysis

Let $F:U \to \mathbb{R}$ harmonica in a open $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, suppose that the critical points of f are all non-degenerate, show that f does not have maximum or minimum local.

I was trying to do the absurd proof:

suppose that f has maximum then exist $\delta >0$  such that $\|v \|<\delta$ then $f(a+v)<f(a)$ as $a$  maximum it follows that it is critical point, well I am stuck, I dont know  how to use hypotheses to find an absurdity

Answer (score 1):

A hint:

Consider a critical point $p\in U$. You have to look at the Hessian of $f$ at $p$. Given that $\Delta F(p)=0$ you can say something about the eigenvalues of the Hessian at $p$.